# Androidソフトキーボードでスクロールする

Tags: android, xml

AndroidStudioでソフトウェアキーボードを作成しています。
ようやく単純な10キーが完成したので，今は記号を実装しているところです。
以下のxmlはその一部ですが，Rowが10行あるため，10キーのように単純に実装すると画面が埋め尽くされてしまいます。
標準のキーボードのように上下にスクロールできるようにするにはどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

```
<!-- app/res/xml/sign.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="33.33%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="40dp">
    <Row> 
        <Key android:codes="40" android:keyLabel="(" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="41" android:keyLabel=")"/>
        <Key android:codes="123" android:keyLabel="{"/>
        <Key android:codes="125" android:keyLabel="}" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <!-- キーボードは8列11行の予定 -->
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```